# Modal not overlapping scrollbar

Tags: html, css, materialize

**Problem:**

The Table on the page gets a overflow when needed.

When I press "assets" and "add assets" There comes a modal where I can add a "Asset". The modal overlaps all items on the body except the scrollbar of the table.

[image]

As you can see on the image at the input "GPS tracker ID" there is a scrollbar.

I am using [Materialize modals](https://materializecss.com/modals.html) and [Materialize Table](https://materializecss.com/table.html) for this project.

**Question:**

How can I overlap the scrollbar as well?

**Code:**

```js
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    // var options = 
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, {coverTrigger: false});
  });
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#map{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
nav{
  background-color:#1A9988 !important; 
}
/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
#form_btn{
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-popup{
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 25%;
}
/*form box*/
.form-container {
  padding: 20px !important;
  background-color: white;
}
.login{
  color: #1A9988;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.Sign-up, .Sign-up:visited{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #1A9988;
  text-decoration: underline;
  float: none !important;
  clear: both;
}
#form_full{
  background-color: white;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#Sign-up{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.not-a-user{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #707070;
}
.Cancel{
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #707070;
}
.Sign-up_Cancel{
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #1A9988;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#row_link{
  margin-left:  0;
}
.alert {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
#login_alert{
  top: 0;
}
/*table with gps trackers*/
.Assets{
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}

.link{
  color: #1a9988;
}
.link:hover{
  color:  #0f7567;
}
/*popup add assets style*/
/* The Modal (background) */
.add_assets {
  left: 0;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 55%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
}
#submit{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  right:30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#Cancel_add{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  left:30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 5s;
  animation: animatezoom 5s
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
  
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .Assets::-webkit-scrollbar {
    z-index:10;
  }
  /*asset table*/
  .Assets{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  /*add asset popup style*/
  .add_assets {
    left: 0;
    top: 10%;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 80%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  }
  #submit, #Cancel_add{
    width: auto;
  }
  .modal-content{
    padding: 0;
  }
  #form_full{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  #Sign-up{
    width: 50%;
    right: 10px;
  }
  .Cancel{
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #e-mail, #password, #name , #GPS_ID, #info{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Add asset</a></li>
</ul>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
        <li class="active"><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Assets<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="?logout=1">Uitloggen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </nav>
<body>
<table class='Assets responsive-table centered highlight'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset name</th>
      <th>GPS_ID</th>
      <th>Info</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
 <!-- add asset form -->
 <div id="modal1" class="modal add_assets modal2">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Voeg asset toe</h4>
    <form class="col s12 animate" action="" method="post">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="name">
     <input class="validate" type="text" required name="name">
             <label for="Name">Asset name</label>
             <span class="helper-text" data-error="Veld mag niet leeg zijn" data-success="correct">Geef de GPS tracker een naam</span>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="GPS_ID">
     <input class="validate" type="number" required name="GPS_ID">
             <label for="GPS_ID">GPS tracker ID</label>
             <span class="helper-text" data-error="Moet een nummer zijn" data-success="correct">Example: 32043123</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="info">
     <input class="validate" type="text" required name="info">
             <label for="Info">Other gps info</label>
             <span data-error="Veld mag niet leeg zijn" data-success="correct" class="helper-text">Extra info over de GPS</span>
    </div>
   </div>
       <div class="input-group">
         <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
      </div>
         <button id="Cancel_add" type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light modal-close" >Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

**To simulate my problem:**

I am using Firefox as browser (with mobile simulator).
(in for example Chrome you don't have this problem because the scrollbar is auto hiding)

1. Open the snippet as full page and open the console.
2. Use the firefox mobile simulator to minify the screen.
3. Press 'Assets' in the nav bar
4. In the drop-down press 'Add assets'
5. The modal will open and you will see the scrollbar overlapping the modal.

Every tip/ help is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the example you have given, there is no such issues it seems..

Comment: By looking into the picture i am sure its the issue with `z-index`, make modal `z-index` higher or lower the scroll container... As you code seems ok

Comment: @ManirajMurugan when you simulate the snippet to full page and then make the browser smaller with the console you will see the table gets a scroll bar when you press 'assets' and then 'add assets' the modal will show up. But the scrollbar of the table is overlapping the modal.

Comment: @Awais I tried to do that but it did nothing. Materialize also gives the modal a standard z-index of 1003.

Comment: Oh Got it the issue is with the input type number it creates the scroll, try to change it as text just to make sure that the issue is with input or not, because i have tested on Firefox as you mention and i got no scroll,.

Comment: My bad @Awais . Problem is only showing when you use the "mobile device simulator" of Firefox. I will put the code on my hosting to check real quick if the nav bar is also showing on a real mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Big thanks to [@Awais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11393381/awais) for the help.

**The solution:**

Apparently the scroll bar is only showing when u simulate mobile few in Firefox.

When I put the code on hosting and visit the website on my mobile with Firefox browser. There is no scrollbar.

[image: No scrollbar]

Comment: Glad that you helped yourself to get rid of that problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, when the modal window places near the other blocks, i.e. modal is a sibling for the rest blocks. And when the modal window is visible, all the sibling's scroll bars are visible above the modal but the content is hidden under the modal.

So it looks like we have 2 separate z-indexes of the bottom block: for the content and for the scroll bar. I.e. only the scroll bar's "z-index"(which does not exist of course) is more than the modal, but the content's "z-index" (which does not exist too) is less than modal's z-index.

**Solution:**
In my case, I did not add z-index to the sibling's blocks, but added it to the modal. I.e. after *adding z-index to sibling's divs* this problem has disappeared.

It seems like a browser bug. I understand that we should add the correct z-index value and all will be good, but I can't understand why it works in this way.